# ¿Cómo puedo hacer mis botones mas pequeños usando `xaml - windows phone`?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone

Este es el codigo de mis botones redondos:

```
<Button  Name="Arriba" 
             Width="100" 
             Height="100" 
             Content="+" 
             Margin="85,155,0,400" 
             Click="Arriba_Click">

        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid>
                    <Ellipse Fill="Red"/>
                    <ContentPresenter  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>

    </Button>
```

Quiero que sean de 30x30 pero ya no puedo hacerlos mas pequeños

Answer (score 2):

Debes modificar las propiedades **Width** y **Height** del control **Button**:

```
<Button Name="Arriba"  
        Content="+" 
        Margin="5"
        Width="30"
        Height="30" 
        Click="Arriba_Click" >
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <Grid>
                <Ellipse Stroke="Red"
                         StrokeThickness="2">
                    <Ellipse.Fill>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="Red" />
                    </Ellipse.Fill>
                </Ellipse>
                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                  VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

Comment: ya modifique esas propiedades pero no me deja hacer mas pequeños los botones, ya lo resolví es con estas prodiedades

MinWidth y MinHeight